# Homomorphism between group of deck transformations and N(H)

Tags: algebraic-topology

Consider a connected covering $p:(\tilde{X},\tilde{x}_0) \to (X, x_0)$ with $H:= p_*(\pi_1(\tilde{X},\tilde{x}_0)$ and $N(H)$ the normalizer of $H$ in $\pi_1(X, x_0)$.

I'm trying to show that the map $\phi : N(H) \to \Gamma(\tilde{X})$ which takes $[\gamma]$ to the deck transformation uniquely determined by the endpoint of the lift $\tilde{\gamma}$ starting at $\tilde{x}_0$ is a homomorphism, that is, $\phi([\alpha]) \cdot \phi([\beta]) = \phi([\alpha] \cdot [\beta])$.

It seems like the composition $\phi([\alpha]) \cdot \phi([\beta])$ could very well take $\tilde{x_0}$ to a different point than $\tilde{\beta} \circ \tilde{\alpha}$.

I thought the fact that the lifts of $[\alpha \cdot \beta]$ and $[\alpha] \cdot [\beta]$ must have the same endpoint might be helpful but I'm not sure.

Comment: What is $N(H)$?

Comment: The normalizer of H in $\pi_1(X , x_0)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\tilde{\alpha}$ and $\tilde{\beta}$ be the lifts of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ starting at $\tilde{x}_0$ with endpoints labeled $\tilde{x}_\alpha$, $\tilde{x}_\beta$, respectively. We then find that $\tilde{\alpha} \cdot \phi([\alpha])(\tilde{\beta})$ is *the* lift of $\alpha \cdot \beta$ starting at $\tilde{x}_0$ with endpoint $\phi([\alpha])(\tilde{x}_\beta) = (\phi([\alpha]) \circ \phi([\beta]))(\tilde{x}_0)$, i.e. $\phi([\alpha]) \circ \phi([\beta]) = \phi([\alpha] \cdot [\beta])$.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to mention that the covering is connected, but you assumed this in your answer anyways. I will edit the post to reflect this

Comment: Oh, whoops :) Good catch.